# List posts in the wordpress theme customiser

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Hey there.** I am creating a Wordpress theme and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to list one of my custom post types in the theme customiser. I have a custom post type called "slideshow" that has custom meta boxes etc and is designed just for slideshows. I would like to be able to list these posts in a dropdown inside the ***customiser***. Ideally ending up with them in the array like this...
    'the_id' => 'Slideshow post title',

```
            $wp_customize->add_setting(
              'slideshow-homepage',
              array(
                'default' => 'none',
               )
              );

            $wp_customize->add_control(
              'slideshow-homepage',
              array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'priority' => 3,
                'label' => 'Slideshow',
                'description' => '',
                'section' => 'homepage',
                'choices' => array(

                'somehow' => 'somehow',
                'list' => 'list',
                'all' => 'all',
                'custom' => 'custom',
                'post' => 'post',
                'types' => 'types',
                'of' => 'of',
                'type' => 'type',
                'slideshow' => 'slideshow'

                ),
              )
            );
```

Many thanks guys and girls. Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
              'slideshow-homepage',
              array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'priority' => 3,
                'label' => 'Slideshow',
                'description' => '',
                'section' => 'homepage',
                'choices' => array_reduce( 
                    get_posts( 'post_type=slideshow&posts_per_page=-1' ), 
                    function( $result, $item ) { 
                        $result[$item->ID] = $item->post_title;
                        return $result;
                    }
                ),
              )
            );
```

To add an empty field as well:

```
$posts = array_reduce( 
        get_posts( 'post_type=slideshow&posts_per_page=-1' ), 
        function( $result, $item ) { 
            $result[$item->ID] = $item->post_title;
            return $result;
        }
    );
    $none = array('' => 'None');
    $choices = $none + $posts;

    $wp_customize->add_control('slideshow_control', array(
        'label'      => __('Choose Slideshow', 'themename'),
        'section'    => 'slideshow_option',
        'settings'   => 'slideshow_settings',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => $choices
    ));
```

Comment: wasn't sure what your post type was called. glad it worked out.

Comment: Worked out very well and thank you, would you by any chance know how to include a default in the reduced array? i.e. "none" => "None"   ...and again, thanks

Comment: Oh you absolute star! I was just in the php manual looking at array_merge but you pipped me to it! I am so grateful for people like you who know what you are talking about!

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, I really am, and I am so grateful for your help. Would you possibly know of a way to get the post ID as opposed to having the array listing out numbers incrementally as the ID. Currently I can select from the dropdown and render an ID but the selected ID changes when I add a new post of the type "slideshow". Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh i see. I updated my answer. Instead of `array_merge` use the `+` operator